# Implicit conversion to Runnable?

Tags: scala, runnable, implicit-conversion

As an exercise, I tried to create an implicit conversion that would accept a function and produce a `Runnable`. That way you could call Java methods that accept `Runnable` objects and use them like closures.

The implicit conversion is easy enough:

```
    implicit def funToRunnable(fun : Unit) = new Runnable() { def run = fun }
```

However I don't know how to call it. How do you pass in a no-arg function that returns Unit, without having it be evaluated at once? For example, I'd like the following to print "12" but instead it prints "21" because `print("2")` is evaluated at once.

```
    var savedFun : Runnable = null
    def save(r : Runnable) = { savedFun = r }

    save(print("2"))
    print("1")
    savedFun.run()
```

How do I tell the compiler to treat `print("2")` as the body of a function, not something to be evaluated at once? Some possibilities I tried, such as

```
    save(() => print("2"))
```

or

```
    save(=> print("2"))
```

are not legal syntax.

Comment: you meant *"call java methods that accept Runnables and pass functions into them like closures"*? because methods that accept other functions are not called closures; the functions they accept are called (sometimes) closures.

Answer (score 24):

arg, just answered my own question. I implemented the implicit conversion incorrectly. The correct implementation is

```
implicit def funToRunnable(fun: () => Unit) = new Runnable() { def run() = fun() }
```

and you call it like this:

```
save(() => print("2"))
```

This will yield "2"

Comment: I was on the same track. Do you have any idea on why `def run  = run` doesn't work?

Comment: `def run = run` will always be an infinite recursion. Even if there's a `run` defined in an enclosing scope, the one defined by this `def` will shadow it, guaranteeing a direct, unconditional recursive call.

Comment: I meant `def run = fun` without parens

Comment: @Support because fun without parentheses just creates a method that returns the function that was passed. To call a function type, you have to use parentheses, otherwise you're just returning the funciton itself.

Comment: Shouldnt it yield 2 instead of 12?

Answer (score 14):

If you wanted to live dangerously, you could convert anything to a runnable:

```
implicit def whateverToRunnable[F](f: => F) = new Runnable() { def run() { f } }

scala> val t = new Thread(println("Hello"))
t: java.lang.Thread = Thread[Thread-2,5,main]

scala> t.start()
Hello
```

Or you could create your own thread-creator-and-starter:

```
def thread[F](f: => F) = (new Thread( new Runnable() { def run() { f } } )).start

scala> thread { println("Hi"); Thread.sleep(1000); println("Still here!") }
Hi

scala> Still here!
```

If you wanted to return the thread, then

```
def thread[F](f: => F) = {
  val t = new Thread( new Runnable() { def run() { f } } )
  t.start()
  t
}
```

But all of this, while useful, is perhaps even less useful than `scala.actors.Futures` (tested only on 2.8):

```
scala> import scala.actors.Futures

scala> val x = Futures.future { Thread.sleep(10000); "Done!" }
x: scala.actors.Future[java.lang.String] = <function0>

scala> x.isSet
res0: Boolean = false

scala> x.isSet
res1: Boolean = false

scala> x()   // Waits until the result is ready....
res2: java.lang.String = Done!
```

Answer (score 5):

Interesting, this way you can execute code that receives a `Runnable` and pass it a closure.

See:

```
scala> new Thread( ()  => print( "Hello" ) ).start()
<console>:5: error: overloaded method constructor Thread with alternatives (java.lang.ThreadGroup,java.lang.Runnable,java.lang.String,Long)java.lang.Thread <and> (java.lang.ThreadGroup,java.lang.Runnable,java.lang.String)java.lang.Thread <and> (java.lang.Runnable,java.lang.String)java.lang.Thread <and> (java.lang.ThreadGroup,java.lang.String)java.lang.Thread <and> (java.lang.String)ja...
       new Thread( ()  => print( "Hello" ) ).start()


scala> implicit def funcToRunnable( func : () => Unit ) = new Runnable(){ def run() = func() }
funcToRunnable: (() => Unit)java.lang.Object with java.lang.Runnable

scala> def doRun( runnable: Runnable ) = runnable.run
doRun: (Runnable)Unit

scala> doRun( () => print("Hola"))
Hola

scala> new Thread(()=>print("Hello")).start()

scala> Hello
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you can do it even nicer with call-by-name argument:

```
implicit def runnable(f: => Unit): Runnable = new Runnable() { def run() = f }
```

Usage:

```
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global._
execute(print("hello"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to run some code in a different thread:

```
scala.actors.Actor.actor { ...doSomething()... }
```

Comment: Runnable is not only used to run stuff in a newly Threads. For example in GUI development it is used to run stuff on the special UI thread.